# How to calculate the number of connected components in a non amplitude directed graph?

Tags: c++

I am trying to calculate how many amplitude traversals I need to have the total number of groups connected. Below is my code that performs the amplitude traversal. What could I do to count the groups? Initially, the default traversal starts at node 0.

---

```
#include <deque> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
 
int main( ) { 
   int n, m;                   // n vertice, m edges 
   std::cin >> n >> m; 
 
   std::vector<int> adjacent[n]; 
   for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) { 
      int x, y; 
      std::cin >> x >> y; 
      adjacent[x].push_back(y); 
      adjacent[y].push_back(x); 
   } 
 
   int origen = 0; 
   std::deque<int> cola = { origen }; 
   std::vector<bool> processed(n,false); 
   int res =0; 
     do { 
         int current= cola.front( ); 
         cola.pop_front( ); 
            if (!processed[current]) { 
                 processed[current] = true; 
                 std::cout << actual << " "; 
                 for (int vecino : adjacent[current]) { 
                  cola.push_back(vecino); 
               } 
            } 
 
   } while (!cola.empty( )); 
 
}
```

---

Input:

```
6   
4   
0 5
2 4
2 3
4 3
```

Comment: Pick any vertex, perform the traversal. Pick any vertex not yet visited, perform the traversal again. Continue until all vertices have been visited. Every time you had to do "pick any vertex" is one connected component.

Comment: I understand that I have to do that, only that I don't know how to change the vertex once they have finished turning "true" in the first traversal, my problem is the implementation of this in the code

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You have `processed` vector - are you saying you don't know how to find a `false` element in it?

Comment: I mean that I don't know how to change the node after making the first traversal and without emptying the queue

Comment: What do you mean, without emptying the queue? By the time the `do/while` loop exits, the queue must be empty (or it wouldn't have exited). You need another loop around all that - a loop that finds some index `v` in `processed` for which `processed[v] == false`, pushes `v` onto the queue (so it now has one element), and runs the traversal again. Continue until no such `v` could be found.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I have what I wanted :)